# How to get data from socket methods?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have connected to one socket using webSocket library. https://www.varvet.com/blog/using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps/

compile "org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0"

Now I want to get data from socket.

In javascript the code is like :

```
socket : io.connect('52.11.67.123:6060', { query: {user:JSON.stringify({user:usercus}) ,login:JSON.stringify({username:'escr',password:'escrowandt'})}}),
thats for connection
MY_Socket.socket.emit('getBids');
      MY_Socket.socket.emit('getHistory');
```

How should I call this getBid and getHistory in android?

My code for connecting socket :

```
  private void connectWebSocket() {
       URI uri;
       try {
           JSONObject authenticate = new JSONObject();
           authenticate.put("username", "escr");
           authenticate.put("password", "escrowandt");

         Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
           builder.scheme("ws")
                   .encodedAuthority("52.11.67.123:6060")
                   .appendEncodedPath("socket.io/")
                   .appendQueryParameter("user", sessionData.getString("customer_id", ""))
                   .appendQueryParameter("login", String.valueOf(authenticate));

           String myUrl = builder.build().toString()+"&EIO=3&transport=websocket";

           Log.e("socket:", myUrl);
           uri = new URI(myUrl);
           Log.e("socket1:", uri.toString());

           mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
               @Override
               public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                   Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
                   mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
                   mWebSocketClient.send("getHistory");
                   mWebSocketClient.send("getBids");
               }



               @Override
               public void onMessage(String s) {
                   final String message = s;
                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {

                           Log.i("responseFromWebSocket",message);

                       }
                   });
               }

               @Override
               public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                   Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
               }

               @Override
               public void onError(Exception e) {
                   Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
               }
           };
           mWebSocketClient.connect();

       }
            catch (JSONException e) {
           }catch (URISyntaxException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               return;
           }
   }
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: `Now I want to get data from socket.

In javascript the code is like :`. No. That looks more like sending data with a socket. emit() will send it i think.

Comment: so how can I send this? @greenapps

Comment: `mWebSocketClient.send("getBids");` ?

Comment: I tried this, but I did not get the proper response, in onMessage method I get message 40.

Comment: So you got message 40. You are very informative. Thank you.

Comment: sorry? can you help  me with it?

Comment: So you got message 40. Thats all info we get? Are you serious?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157704/discussion-between-sid-and-greenapps).

Comment: If you want to chat you are not serious.